# Change Ubuntu Touch Nexus4 channel

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch

When I try to change my Ubuntu touch channel on my dual boot Nexus4 to gain GPS advanced support, then first block being copied returns "Permission Denied" error.
What am I missing?
I am using the current Ubuntu touch stable channel so I must have unlocked the phone.

```
adb reboot recovery

ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use ubuntu-device-flash to change channel. Just use 'system-image-cli --switch CHANNEL' directly on the phone http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/system-image-cli.1.html Note: it can sometimes take a while and it doesn't give alot of status feedback but just let it run to the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to reboot into recovery. The device needs just to be booted up normally and the developer mode needs to be enabled.

The command you used looks pretty fine, so simply try your command again while the device is booted up normally.